# Java Base Conversion with addition

Tags: java, addition, base-conversion

How would I do 10101base2  +   111base2 =?
I already know how to convert the base to another base.
But how would I do them with addition?

Comment: Convert each separately then add them.

Comment: Numbers are numbers - doesn't matter what you're doing with them.

Comment: Why would you want to add another step for yourself and convert to decimal? Just add them as binary numbers (I'm assuming your end result will be binary as well)

Answer (score 2):

I find java's [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to be the best among them all for bit manipulation. Among its wide usages *(mainly with storing huge numbers and for its wide array of supported operations)*, you do have the option for base conversion from 2 to 36. As for addition of these binary digits, you can use `BigInteger.add(BigIntger)`function provide by them.

**Example :**

```
BigInteger num_1=new BigInteger("10101",2);     //Store as Binary
BigInteger num_2=new BigInteger("111",2);       //Store as Binary
BigInteger result=num_1.add(num_2);

//Display the result using BigInteger.toString(int base)
System.out.println("Result = "+result.toString(10));    //Showing result in Decimal base here
```

Ofcourse, if its having fractional digits, the method described by [William Gaul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19018138/7550472) is to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = 0b10101 + 0b111;
```

Or if your inputs are strings:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt("10101", 2) + Integer.parseInt("111", 2);
```

EDIT: If you're asking how to *view* the result in binary form, there's also this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```